# Rails: Nested resource and specifying the "nester"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

A company has many properties. A property has one company.

In my routes file I got:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :property_managers
end
```

In the property_manager_controller, my `create` action looks like this (default scaffold implementation slightly modified to accommodate the company):

```
def create   
@property_manager = PropertyManager.new(params[:property_manager])
@property_manager.company_id = params[:company_id]

respond_to do |format|
  if @property_manager.save
    format.html { redirect_to company_property_managers_path, notice: 'Property manager was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @property_manager, status: :created, location: @property_manager }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @property_manager.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Is there a way in which I do not have to explicitly set the company_id, since it is known within the context of the URL/route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could do something like the following, not sure if it's better or not:

```
class PropertyManagersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_company

  def new
    @property_manager = @company.property_managers.build
  end

  def create
    @property_manager = @company.property_managers.build(params[:property_manager])
    respond_to do |format|
      ...
    end
  end

  private

  def find_company
    @company ||= Company.find(params[:company_id])
  end

end
```